# Is my Fourier Transform of this function correct?

Tags: fourier-transform

I need to find the Fourier transform of this function:

$f(x) = \frac{A}{4} t(U_0(t+4) - U_0(t-4))$

My answer is

$F(s) = \frac{A}{4} (\frac{8\cos(4s)}{s} + \frac{2\sin(4s)}{s^2})$, assuming $U_0(t)$ is a step function.

Comment: Since we don't know what function $U_0(t)$ is, there is no way we can say if you are right.

Comment: Is it true if I assumed it is a step function?